# Formating this date type with moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a javascript datetime picker which generated a time in this format: `2017-09-03T11:37:00.000Z`

Now, I am trying to set default value of december 31, 2007 but I don't know how to generate it with the format the datepicker uses.

I have done [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qk8vm94p/):

```
var original = '2017-09-03T11:37:00.000Z'; 
var recreate = moment().endOf('year').format('YYYY-MM-HH:MM-SS:MS');
alert(recreate) // 2017-12-23:12-99:129
```

but the format isn't the same

Comment: What is expected format?

Comment: What you want to show?

Comment: @GovindSamrow `2017-09-03T11:37:00.000Z` but only for the end of the current year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This format is known as ISO date format. You can convert moment to this format by calling corresponding function:

```js
var original = '2017-09-03T11:37:00.000Z'; 
var recreate = moment().endOf('year').toISOString();
alert(recreate)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qk8vm94p/2/)

Answer (score 2):

toDate() to get it in correct format.
check this

```
var original = '2017-09-03T11:37:00.000Z'; 
var recreate = moment().endOf('year');

alert(moment(recreate).toDate());
```